# How to implement dynamically a view from controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5, ui5-tooling

i need your help please, i have this view that i want to implement dynamically

```html
<mvc:View   
    controllerName="kommissionierung1.controller.GroupeFamilial"    
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:grid="sap.ui.layout.cssgrid"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
      xmlns:f="sap.f">
  <IconTabBar id="IconTabBarID" stretchContentHeight="true" backgroundDesign="Transparent" applyContentPadding="false" expanded="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" >
    <items>
      <IconTabFilter text="Famille Douala" >
        <ScrollContainer height="100%" width="100%" horizontal="false" vertical="true">
          <f:GridList id="FormPart4"  items="{GroupeFamiliale>/results}" mode="SingleSelect" selectionChange="onSelectionChange_Click" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
            <f:customLayout>
              <grid:GridBasicLayout gridTemplateColumns="repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr))" gridGap="0.5rem" />
              <grid:GridBoxLayout boxWidth="15.5rem" />
            </f:customLayout>

          <f:GridListItem press="onGroup_Click" type="Active" highlightText="Famille par groupage" id="gridListID" >
            <VBox height="50%" class="sapUiSmallMargin">
              <layoutData>
                <FlexItemData growFactor="1" shrinkFactor="0" />
              </layoutData>
              <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin" >
                <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                  <core:Icon
                    src="sap-icon://group"
                    size="2.625rem"
                    color="Default"
                    class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom" />
                </HBox>
                <Title text="Groupe familial"  class="customTextFontSize"  wrapping="true" id="group_Name"/>
                <Text text="{
                              path: 'GroupeFamilial>NumerosIdentifiant',
                               formatter: '.formatter.ConvertToIntFormat' }"  class="customTextFontSize" id="group_Ident"/>
                </VBox>
              </VBox>
            </f:GridListItem>
          </f:GridList>
        </ScrollContainer>
      </IconTabFilter>
    </items>
  </IconTabBar>
</mvc:View>
```

i don't really understand how to do it with JS. the reasons are that we can have in Icontabfilter from 1...n Tabs, depending of what the model give us back. eg:
Today: we just have 1 TabFilter with 2 items.
Tomorrow: we have suddently n Tabfilter. n1 has for example 2 items, n2 has 20 items, n3 maybe just 1 item...n
Please any help and solution are welcome

Thx in advance

Comment: Do you want to have dynamic tabs or do you want to have dynamic content in your tabs?

Comment: Hi Marc i want to have dynamic tabs.

Comment: Then bind the `items` aggregation of your `IconTabBar` to a model.

Comment: you mean dynamically or on my actuual view?

Comment: Usually you first connect the model with your view (not necessary if your model is created in manifest.json or Component.js). Then you can use your model in your XML and bind single properties or aggregations of your controls to your model data.

Comment: Many thanks Marc, i have just to add in my View the attributs items= myModel and it display dependently of my Data the iconTabFilter as exprected  `<IconTabBar id="IconTabBarID" stretchContentHeight="true" backgroundDesign="Transparent" applyContentPadding="false" expanded="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" **items="GroupeFamiliale>/results"** >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks Marc, i have just to add in my View the attributs items= myModel and it display dependently of my Data the iconTabFilter as exprected

`<IconTabBar id="IconTabBarID" stretchContentHeight="true" backgroundDesign="Transparent" applyContentPadding="false" expanded="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" ** items="GroupeFamiliale>/results" ** >`